# Form data not being sent to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have a form that pops up in a modal when the user clicks a button in the search results of a query. This form has three input fields and a few other fields that are being appended to it once the submit button is being clicked using ajax. As this is apart of a Django app, I am catching the values in the view on the server-side. I'm successfully able to get the data from the input fields of the form, but I'm not able to get the data from the appended fields.

I'm fairly new to using ajax so its likely that I'm doing something wrong but it seems like the data should be getting sent to the server. What could be the problem?

Here is the code for the ajax call and the modal form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#mform").submit(function(){
    var c = getCookie('csrftoken');
    //var data1 = $().attr("");
    var extraData = [];
    extraData['venue'] = $("#invite").data("venue");
    extraData['artist'] = $("#invite").data("artist");
    extraData['f_date'] = $("#invite").data("formatted_date");
    extraData['uf_date'] = $("#invite").data("date");
    extraData['ticket_url'] =  $("#invite").data("ticket_url");
    extraData['city'] = $("#invite").data("city");
    extraData['region'] = $("#invite").data("region");
    extraData['artist'] = $("#invite").data("artist");
    var PostData = {csrfmiddlewaretoken: c, additionalValues:extraData}
    $ajax({
        //context:this,
        type : 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/artistsearch/',
        data: JSON.stringify(PostData),
        success: function(response){}
    });
});
```

#### EDIT:

**HTML containing data to be sent**

```
    <ul class= 'list-group'>
    {% for ticket in data %}
        <li  class = 'list-group-item' >
            Title: {{ticket.title}}
            Location: {{ticket.formatted_location}}
            Venue: {{ticket.venue.name}}
            Date: {{ticket.formatted_datetime}}
            tickets status: {{ticket.ticket_status}}<br>
            <a href = {{ticket.ticket_url}}> ticket url</a>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <button id = 'invite' type='button' class= 'btn btn-info btn-lg' data-toggle = 'modal' data-target='#myModal' data-artist = {{ticket.artists.name}} data-venue={{ticket.venue.name}} data-date = {{ticket.datetime}} data-formatted_date = {{ticket.formatted_datetime}} data-city= {{ticket.venue.city}} data-region = {{ticket.venue.region}} data-ticket_url={{ticket.ticket_url}} > Invite a friend </button>    
                <button id = 'save' type = 'button' class = 'btn btn-primary-outline'> Save Concert </button>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Would you mind reducing the code to the minimum runnable code that shows your problem?

Comment: What do you mean by appended fields?

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak No problem, I took out the view function since it was only catching the data.

Comment: @Serjik I meant that when the button (which launches the modal) is clicked, the jquery event handler function runs and is supposed to add fields to the form to be sent to the server-side.

Comment: If you want to add fields, then add hidden html inputs to the form. What when you're doing is sending a request through JavaScript aside from your form. When you click the submit button you're doing another POST which does not contain the previously sent data.

Comment: Ah wait, you're scrapping the data through jQuery there. Are you sure extraData is properly populated when sending? For example, what is $("invite") supposed to match?

Comment: Also you might want to prevent the default submit action. I think you are currently submitting the form twice. For this add argument event to the anonymous JS function and inside the function, call event.preventDefault()

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak I just added the corresponding html for the ajax call.

Comment: Ok, some of your HTML is not valid and the id selector should be "#invite" (note the # sign). As for your HTML there must be no space around "=" and any attribute values must be inside quotes. Since you can't simply add random attributes to HTML elements please either use the HTML5 data API (google it) or use hidden fields for that.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the # selector for id invite of button it should be like $("#invite"). Use attribute like data-artist instead of just artist and get it like $("#invite").data("artist) or $("#invite").attr("data-artist).

And then post it like ....

var postData = {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: c,
            additionalValues: extraData
         }
 Then post data like

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'URL here',
        data:JSON.stringify(PostData),
       // .......
      //   Other code here

        )};
```

Comment: I added in the code, but I'm still having the same problem, do I need the line for ```context: this``` or something? I updated the post with the most recent code.

Comment: You are not getting attributes values inside the ajax call or after post in the server? If you not getting inside the ajax call then try to make it hidden fields. If it works then that means there is problem picking up the attribute.

Comment: I have updated my answer using data-attr instead of using just artist as attribute in the button. Check it out . Second you can use input hidden fields.

Comment: I was following [this site](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/) when trying to make the code compliant with html5, but for some reason, the data is still not coming through after the POST request is made as I'm printing out the variables and seeing the ```None``` type. I've updated the post with what I've just tried. How would I go about adding hidden fields as an alternative?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if the ajax call is working at all b/c I added both console.logs and alerts after the extra data was stored in the array, and nothing happened.

Comment: Have you checked the values of data-attributes in inspect element of button?